# Assembly Language: Adding odd numbers from a location

Tags: assembly

I had a question on assembly language. I know how to add and subtract numbers. But I'm stuck on adding numbers that are odd and set them to a location.

Question: 
Take the numbers from location 0050-0059, add the sum of all numbers that are odd and store them in 005A.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you test if number is odd? How the computer stores integers in memory? Can you easily tell if number is odd or not? Try few numbers, how the CPU sees them, to see if you can figure out something or not.

Comment: If you are able to add numbers successfully, I'm not sure how adding odd numbers is any different.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test if a number is odd by testing its least significant bit.

```
//edx holds a pointer to 0x0050....
//set total to zero
@loopstart:
mov eax,[edx]
test eax,1                   //non-destructive `and reg,1`
jz @even                     //if LSB = 0 then even, skip adding code
@odd:                        //LSB=1, thus odd, do the adding.
//add the numbers
@even:
//increase the pointer
//decrease the counter
//loop
@done:
//store the sum
```